# How to remove square brackets from string?

Tags: python, string

I want to remove the both of the square brackets in the output of my code.

My code:

```
request2 = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId=1045618&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
json2 = request2.json()
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for fluc in selection['flucs'][0]:
        flucs1 = ast.literal_eval(selection['flucs'])
        flucs2 = flucs1[-2:]
        flucs3 = [[x[1]] for x in flucs2]
```

Example output of code:

```
[[12.97], [13.13]]
```

Desired output of code:

```
12.97, 13.13
```

Comment: Is the output a string or a list of lists?

Comment: Just add another [0]. [12.97] is a one-item list, so pick the first item in it and you'll get the desired output.

Comment: Where do I add this [0]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what is in the `json2` variable (i.e. the _input_).

Answer (score 0):

using str.replace method

```
    n = [[12.97], [13.13]]
        
        
    m = str(n)[1:-1] # convert list into str to be able to use str.replace method
        
        
    z = m.replace('[', '', 3) 
    y = z.replace(']', '', 3)
    
    
    print(y)
```

output

```
12.97, 13.13
```

Answer (score 0):

or using regex

```
import re

al = [1, 2, [5, 6], 8, 9]

z = re.sub(r'\[', '', str(al)) 
y = re.sub(r'\]','', z) 

print(y)
```

ouput

```
1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` also help to join list of list like this way:

```
output = [[12.97], [13.13]]
result = '\n'.join(','.join(map(str, row)) for row in output)
print(result)
```

output :

```
12.97
13.13
```

also try this :

```
result2 = ', '.join(','.join(map(str, row)) for row in output)
print(result2)
```

output:

```
 12.97, 13.13
```